# Logging out all cookied users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 app which used to have indefinite timeouts, so users weren't logged out until they actually clicked the 'log out' link. This was changed a few weeks back using the code below in Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(29),
    SlidingExpiration =true
});
```

The problem is that there are users who were cookied before the change who still seem to be logged in. Is there a way of logging out these users without deploying a change to the app to store/check for an extra value in the cookie?

Comment: clear the cache of device

Comment: Have a check on the request which checks if the cookie expiry is longer than 30mins, if so delete the cookie or change the auth cookie name then any existing cookies would be invalid

Comment: Change the auth cookie name, sounds like it could work. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the sliding expiration feature, .NET should read and rewrite the cookie with every page request, so the change should be picked up seamlessly the next time they visit the site. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to introduce SecurityStamp validation. All your cookies already have a value that you can check against, and you don't really need to do much yourself. Add `CookieAuthenticationProvider` to your `CookieAuthenticationOptions` like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(29),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
    },
});
```

This `SecurityStampValidator` will cause the cookies to regenerate every 30 minutes. You can reduce the validation interval as required, but I don't recommend going too short intervals as it'll increase load on your DB. I usually use 10 minutes.

Unfortunately you'll still have to redeploy this change, but not much code for you to write :-)